# Using APA style referencing in elsarticle class document?

Tags: bibtex, lyx, luatex, apa-style

Ive just had my paper sent back to me by the editor of a journal I submitted to and was instructed to change the referencing system of my paper to APA ver. 6 style.

> Text: Citations in the text should follow the referencing style used
>   by the American Psychological Association. You are referred to the
>   Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association, Sixth
>   Edition, ISBN 978-1-4338-0561-5.  APA's in-text citations require the
>   author's last name and the year of publication. You should cite
>   publications in the text, for example, (Smith, 2016).  However, you
>   should not use [Smith, 2016].

I'm using LyX and tried adding `\usepackage{apacite}` but it gave way too many errors. I tried searching for a solution and came across this question: [apacite not working in tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194084/apacite-not-working-in-tex)

Based on the answer there I added `authoryear` in the document class and added the line `\usepackage{apalike}` and `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

This time the document compiled without errors but the referencing within text ins not APA. I should be getting

> (Smith, 2016)

however all my within text references are:

> Smith (2016)

Would appreciate some help here.

**MWE below:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{apalike}
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother
```

and

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

and a reference from my bib file:

```
 % This file was created with JabRef 2.11.
% Encoding: Cp1252


@InProceedings{Xiong2015,
  Title                    = {Text-independent writer identification using SIFT descriptor and contour-directional feature},
  Author                   = {Xiong, Yu-Jie and Wen, Ying and Wang, Patrick SP and Lu, Yue},
  Booktitle                = {Document Analysis and Recognition (ICDAR), 2015 13th International Conference on},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Pages                    = {91--95},
  Publisher                = {IEEE}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Are you using [`natbib` or `biblatex`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299286/64454)?

Comment: Is [change authoryear biblatex citation style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117332/64454) helping?

Comment: @ebo I am using bibtex for referencing. I checked and I appear to not be using any of them I dont have ``\usepackage{natbib}`` in my LaTeX preambles. However adding it in did not change anything.

Comment: It's likely that `\usepackage{natbib}` appear as `\RequirePackage{natbib}` in your class definition. Anyway, I think a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help us help you!

Comment: Have you considered generating citation call-outs via `\citep` instead of `\cite` or `\citet`?

Comment: The `elsarticle` document class loads the `natbib` package automatically.

Comment: understood. Since I'm using LyX, I have copied everything from the source pane and everything before the actual ``\title{}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the desired result. In LyX click on the reference within the text and change the way its displayed in "formatting".

In LaTeX, this can be achieved by using `\citep` instead of `cite`